# Multiple php.ini files

Tags: php, webserver, cherokee

I'd like to use multiple .ini files in a certain PHP instance.

> php-cgi -c /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini -c /var/www/php_oc.ini

I tried something like this but it uses the last defined config file. I'd like to use the default ini as the base and then override directives in the second without using ini_set().

I am using Cherokee as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/var/www
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
```

Comment: I believe that is for Apache? I'm using Cherokee.